# How are results with equal weight sorted when using SPH_SORT_RELEVANCE in Sphinx?

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx

I am using the following code to retrieve search results from Sphinx:

```
$sphinx = new SphinxClient();
$sphinx->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2);
$sphinx->SetRankingMode(SPH_RANK_SPH04);
$result = $sphinx->Query($query, $index);
```

This uses the default sorting of `SPH_SORT_RELEVANCE`. Everything fine.

What I was wondering is, when all results have equal weights (e.g. by using a too general search term), in which order are these returned by Sphinx when using `SPH_SORT_RELEVANCE`? 
Is this the order, in which the documents where added to the index (e.g. in which they where returned by mysql during indexing)? Any other order?

Answer (score 1):

its equivalent to this

```
@weight DESC, @id ASC
```

(an extended sort mode string)